# Debugging a piece of codes in prolog

Tags: prolog

There a piece of codes in Prolog, which is used to convert a txt file to 4 lists( 3 1D_lists one each line, last one is 2D_list, one sublist each line of rest lines.

```
inp :-
    open('3by3data.txt', read, Str),
    read_line_to_string(Str,Line),               %read  a line from Str(Stream)
        split_string(Line," ","",L_list1),       %Split a line into a list by " "
        maplist(atom_number,L_list1,RL), !,      %Conver atom list into number list
    read_line_to_string(Str,Line1),               %read a line from Str(Stream)
        split_string(Line1," ","",L_list2),       %Split a line into a list by " "
        maplist(atom_number,L_list2,FQty), !,    %Conver atom list into number list  

    read_line_to_string(Str,Line2),               %read a line from Str(Stream)
        split_string(Line2," ","",L_list3),       %Split a line into a list by " "
        maplist(atom_number,L_list3,WQty),!,     %Conver atom list into number list      
    read_Costs(Str,Costs),    
    write(RL),nl,write(FQty),nl,write(),nl,write(Costs),nl.


read_Costs(Str,Costs) :- 
        \+at_end_of_stream(Str),
        read_line_to_string(Str,Line3),        
        split_string(Line3," ","",L_list4),  %Split a line into a list by " "
        maplist(atom_number,L_list4,Costs1),%Conver atom list into number list 
        append([costs1],[Costs2],Costs),
        read_Costs(Str,Costs2).
read_Costs([],[]).
```

file.txt:

```
  3   4
  10 60 30 40
  50 30 60
  2 4  5  6
  7 8  9  4
  1 2  4  6
  ...
  =>
  [3,4]
  [10,60,30,40]
  [50,30,60]
  [[2,3,5,6],[7,8,9,4],[1,2,4,6],...]
```

There is a bug for boundary condition in above codes.

Comment: `write()` looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this line

> append([costs1],[Costs2],Costs),

doesn't work, because of mispelling the **variable** Costs1, and the alternative clause on loop termination - at EOF - cannot match the stream `Str` with `[]`.

A note of style about your code. Like any other language, in Prolog there is value in grouping repeated, common functionality in reusable 'subroutines'.

The combination of `read_line_to_string,split_string,maplist(atom_number)` is used so often. Make a service predicate out of them.

If you use SWI-Prolog, you can enhance your parsing with DCGs. For instance

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
:- use_module(library(dcg/high_order)).

parse_3by3data(Rl, FQty, Costs) -->
    a_line_of_numbers(Rl),
    a_line_of_numbers(FQty),
    sequence(a_line_of_numbers,Costs).

a_line_of_numbers(L) -->
    whites,
    sequence(number,whites,L),
    whites, "\n".
```

parse_3by3data//3 is a grammar production you can use directly on files, with phrase_from_file, or strings..., with phrase/3. I.e.

```
test :-
    phrase(parse_3by3data(Rl, FQty, Costs),
` 3   4
  10 60 30 40
  50 30 60
  2 4  5  6
  7 8  9  4
  1 2  4  6
`), writeln(parse_3by3data(Rl, FQty, Costs)).
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works good. I use file directly for '3 4 10 60 ......' , It does work. test is as following:test(file) :- phrase(parse_3by3data(Rl, FQty,WQty, Costs),file), writeln(parse_3by3data(Rl, FQty, WQty,Costs)). Is there any question in this piece of codes?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works good. I use file directly for '3 4 10 60 ......' , It does not  work. test is as following:test(file) :- phrase(parse_3by3data(Rl, FQty,WQty, Costs),file), writeln(parse_3by3data(Rl, FQty, WQty,Costs)). Is there any question in this piece of codes?